# Formatter format method output limit?

Tags: java

I'm on Windows 7 and my Formatter object only wants to write out about 2500 values to file. After that the file is abruptly cut off in the middle of a number, and is just empty after that. I know the while loop is executing the full 4200 times, and iter.next() is returning correct values for all those iterations because I printed them out as it happened. Nevertheless, the actual writing to file part ends after about the 2500th write-out. Any ideas? Thanks!  -Ryan

```
try{...

output = new Formatter("C:\\users\\ryans\\desktop\\IntelMA.tsv");
...
}

...

Iterator<Double> iter = MA.getMovingAverage().iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()){
    output.format("%f\t", iter.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you've never closed or flushed the `Formatter`, so any buffered output will be lost.

You should close it in a `finally` block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The while isn't actually in a try block so I can't use a finally, but I added an output.close(); after the while loop. It still does the same thing - cuts off after about 2500.

Comment: @RyanS: You can (and should) *put* it in a try block then. (Just try/finally). If it's still not working, please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Where you get the data from shouldn't matter (assuming no exceptions are thrown) so I'd start off just looping and printing the index, or maybe random numbers. Anything to reproduce it simply.

Comment: I tried it again this morning and your suggestion worked this time (no idea why it wouldn't work yesterday - user error probably). Thank you very much. I would never have thought of that. I will go ahead and put all the code using the Formatter object into the try block. It's great to have a resource like this to help me learn.